# Landscape Openstack Autopilot stuck at Check list

Tags: openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I am trying to deploy Landscape openstack autopilot with 5 Dell Poweredge R710 server with 3 disk each 2 TB capacity, created raid 5 with 3 virtual drives, stuck at

```
"At least three machines with more than one disk have been commissioned"
```

I logged in one of the node , checked foe disks, got following output.

```
ubuntu@juju-machine-0-lxc-0:~$ ls -l /sys/block | grep sd.
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 26 20:50 sda -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:03:00.0/host2/target2:2:0/2:2:0:0/block/sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 26 20:50 sdb -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:03:00.0/host2/target2:2:1/2:2:1:0/block/sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 26 20:50 sdc -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:03:00.0/host2/target2:2:2/2:2:2:0/block/sdc
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

So, I suspect this is related to MAAS misreporting the disks to Landscape.  There was a similar issue with the Poweredge R610 last year.  See here:

https://github.com/Ubuntu-Solutions-Engineering/openstack-installer/issues/374

I think your best bet would be to report a bug, or contact Canonical support if you're an Ubuntu Advantage customer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Reinstalled MAAS and added all the nodes. After that It passed the check list and Installed Openstack autopilot. It is working like charm now.